# JQuery UI Dialog widget problem with IE and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

The [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) model form widget has an issue with ASP.NET when a button on the dialog is clicked to submit the page. It doesn't work because the form elements in the dialog window are outside the html form tags. So I used the fix of doing  $("#dialog").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));.

It works in Firefox but not in IE because the modal window now appears to be part of the rest of the webpage which is disabled. Visually, this is evident by the stripes showing on both the modal window and the rest of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting the div that contains the dialog inside the form tags to begin with.

Comment: Of course. However the dialog is putting itself outside the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could always submit the form manually by modifying the button to:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  $('form:first').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. You need to append it to the form on open. This worked across all modern browser versions I could find.

```
$('#foobar').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () { $('#foobar').parent().appendTo('form:first') },
    title: 'FOOBAR'
});
```